# Natural language bot with Nodejs (standalone Windows app)

Tags: node.js, nlp, electron

I'm trying to build an electron app that will act like a chat bot, in which you can ask it to do things in natural language and will understand and run the tasks (functions). However I have a gap in knowledge:

- Would the right approach start with the Natural Node library or with some other library specifically for this task like API.AI? Since I'm just starting on AI, would it be better to start with API.AI?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a javascript library that does exactly what you're looking for. It supports 27 languages, with the limitation that in browser chinese is not supported: https://github.com/axa-group/nlp.js

Comment: Thanks @jseijas! One quiestion, if I have intenta that may requiere further questions for parameters, can i do it with this library?

Comment: Yes, it support this feature, called "slot filling". If you use Microsoft bot framework is automatic, if you don't use it you can take a look into the implementation (basically you pass a context object, and form the result copy to it the property slotFilling).

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into this. And if I use the Microsoft framework do I still need an internet connection?

Comment: Well, Microsoft Bot Framework can work offline, but yes, is tricky, because in that case you'll need to build your own connector (There is a Console Connector inside Microsoft Bot Framework that is a good starting point). But of course, for an offline bot, I don't think you need so much.

Comment: Awesome! thanks a lot for your advice! I will try the way you suggested in the previous comment

Comment: hi @jseijas, I've been looking into the library and slot filling. I now have a trained manager that subtracts the entities (slots). However, how could I make it interactive to make the bot ask the questions and finish with a object with all the entities? Also, for this back and forth, can it be possible do it in Electron? cause you need to keep the context of the messages and guide the conversation so I can execute a function once all the information is present

Comment: NlpManager.process has 3 parameters. The last one is the context that you can provide, and will be modified with entities and slotfilling. But you're the responsible of sessions and context, because the library does not assume anything about what you are using as persistance or bot framework. https://github.com/axa-group/nlp.js-app/blob/master/server/feats/agent/agent.controllers.js There in the method "converse" you can find one implementation of it with session stored in database. And about electron: is javascript, you can use it even in frontend.

Comment: This is really good help @jseijas. I'm really sorry to keep bugging you. I did look at your example and understand how you can keep a session and context. Now the question I have is, based on an intent with 2 entities, follow up questions are shown in the result from the process.manager for asking the entity's value, How do I send the remaining of entities values to the manager and have the context updated accordingly? Thanks

Comment: hello @OttoGutierrez, the slot filling process automatically fills the context with the entities values, and also stores an slotFilling property telling the original intent and the current step on the process of slot filling... In the link that I provided, if you use this app, you'll see that the slot filling is automatically done, and the context stored in the session in database.

Comment: I probably didn't ask my question correctly. I'll give you an example. My intent has two entities. In the utterance, it finds one entity and it includes it in the context and the result. As well, it generates another question for asking for the next entity. However, if I submit a second utterance to the same context, will it assign it to the missing entity and complete the intent? This is similar to what you are trying to achieve on open issue #46 for the library

Comment: Well, what you describe is again the definition of Slot Filling. You have an example here with the questions for each entity missed, and the slot filling working: https://github.com/axa-group/nlp.js/blob/master/docs/microsoft-bot-framework.md#recognizer-and-slot-filling  The issue 46 is about executing actions, I mean, not give a text answer but functions and parameters to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

If your objective is to build an app and not really focus on NLP then [DialogFlow](https://dialogflow.com/) is the way to go. There is a [Nodejs client](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow) that you can use and proceed.

If you want to learn NLP then I will suggest you work with Python.

Comment: thanks for the advice. However, I want to have a standalone ElectronJS app. I think DIalogFlow needs a connection to the internet and the app to be hosted on the internet in order to configure the webhook